# Stopwatch start button resets timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, stopwatch

I am making a basic stopwatch, however, each time I start the timer, click stop, and start again wanting to continue my timer, the clock restarts at 0. I'm not quite sure what to do as I just picked up obj-c/Xcode.

```
#import "StopwatchViewController.h"

bool stopPressed = false;
bool startPressed = false;
int startsPressed = 0;
NSTimeInterval totalTimeInterval;

@interface StopwatchViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *stopWatchTimer; // Store the timer that fires after a certain time
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *startDate; // Stores the date of the click on the start button



@end

@implementation StopwatchViewController

- (void)updateTimer
{
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate: self.startDate];
    totalTimeInterval = timeInterval;
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:totalTimeInterval];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];

     NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
     self.stopwatchLabel.text = timeString;



}



- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(startsPressed < 1) {
        if(startPressed) return;
        startPressed = true;
        stopPressed =false;
        self.startDate = [NSDate date];

        //create the stop watch timer that fires every 100ms
        self.stopWatchTimer =
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/100.0
                                     target:self
                                selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
    } else {

        startPressed = true;
        stopPressed = false;

    }
}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender {
    if(stopPressed) return;
    stopPressed = true;
    startPressed = false;
    [self.stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    self.stopWatchTimer  = nil;
    [self updateTimer];
}

- (IBAction)onResetPressed:(id)sender {
    if(stopPressed == false) return;
    self.stopWatchTimer = 0;
    NSString *timeString = @"00:00:00.000";
    self.stopwatchLabel.text = timeString;
}


@end
```

I am currently at this point where my start

```
#import "StopwatchViewController.h"

    bool stopPressed = false;
    bool startPressed = false;
    int startsPressed = 0;
    NSTimeInterval totalTimeInterval;

    @interface StopwatchViewController ()

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *stopWatchTimer; // Store the timer that fires after a certain time
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *startDate; // Stores the date of the click on the start button
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *pauseDate;

    @end

    @implementation StopwatchViewController

    - (void)updateTimer
    {
        NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
        NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate: self.startDate];
        totalTimeInterval = timeInterval;
        NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:totalTimeInterval];

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];

        NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
        self.stopwatchLabel.text = timeString;



    }



    - (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender
    {
    //    if(startsPressed < 1) {
    //        if(startPressed) return;
    //        startPressed = true;
    //        stopPressed =false;
    //        self.startDate = [NSDate date];
    //        
    //        //create the stop watch timer that fires every 100ms
    //        self.stopWatchTimer =
    //        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/100.0
    //                                         target:self
    //                                       selector:@selector(updateTimer)
    //                                       userInfo:nil
    //                                        repeats:YES];
    //    } else {
    //        
    //        startPressed = true;
    //        stopPressed = false;
    //        
    //    }

        if(startsPressed < 1) {
            if( ! _startDate) {
                self.startDate = [NSDate date];
            }
            else {
                if(_pauseDate) {
                    NSTimeInterval startTime = _startDate.timeIntervalSince1970;
                    NSTimeInterval pauseTime = _startDate.timeIntervalSince1970;

                    // the actual elapsed time before we paused
                    NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = pauseTime - startTime;

                    // set a new start time to match our elapsed time.
                    NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate date].timeIntervalSince1970;
                    NSTimeInterval newStartTime = currentTime - elapsedTime;
                    _startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:newStartTime];
                    _pauseDate = nil;
                }
            }


        }
    }


    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    - (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender {
        if(stopPressed) return;
        _pauseDate = [NSDate date];
        stopPressed = true;
        startPressed = false;
        [self.stopWatchTimer invalidate];
        self.stopWatchTimer  = nil;
        [self updateTimer];
    }

    - (IBAction)onResetPressed:(id)sender {
        if(stopPressed == false) return;
        _startDate = nil;
        _pauseDate = nil;
        self.stopWatchTimer = 0;
        NSString *timeString = @"00:00:00.000";
        self.stopwatchLabel.text = timeString;
    }


    @end
```

Comment: It seems that the issue is place in this line: totalTimeInterval = timeInterval; You reset totalTimeInterval every time instead of adding new time interval to current sum.

Comment: @VladimirPopko that code is not the issue. The `totalTimeInterval` is meant to be the difference between the start time and the current time, which is what it does. The issue is that the start time is getting reset every time the timer is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you hit "start", this code gets run:

```
self.startDate = [NSDate date];
```

This resets the start time you are using. Move that out somewhere so that it only happens once instead of on every time you start the timer and I think the result will be closer to what you want. Perhaps you can just store an extra `BOOL` that gets switched the first time the timer is started.

**Edit:**

Very good point brought up by Stonz2 that I overlooked. Doing it this way will cause the time to skip once you start it back up. In order to fix this you will need to store a separate `NSDate` when you stop the timer, to represent the "paused" time. Then, when you are starting the timer back up again, you will need to add the "paused" time to the "start" time so that the continuation is fluid.

## **Edit2:**

I threw this into a project and here is some working code.

I added an extra property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *pauseDate;
```

In `onStopPressed:`, I added this to initialize the pause time:

```
_pauseDate = [NSDate date];
```

Then, in `onStartPressed:`, I added the following code to ensure a single initialization of the `startDate` and to do the math to get the elapsed time after pausing:

```
    // if we have a start date, don't initialize again
    if(! _startDate)
    {
        self.startDate = [NSDate date];
    }
    else
    {
        if(_pauseDate)
        {
            NSTimeInterval startTime = _startDate.timeIntervalSince1970;
            NSTimeInterval pauseTime = _pauseDate.timeIntervalSince1970;

            // The actual elapsed time before we paused.
            NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = pauseTime - startTime;

            // Set a new start time to match our elapsed time.
            NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate date].timeIntervalSince1970;
            NSTimeInterval newStartTime = currentTime - elapsedTime;
            _startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:newStartTime];
            _pauseDate = nil;
        }
    }
```

Also, in order to make your reset work correctly, in `onResetPressed:` you will need to add:

```
_startDate = nil;
_pauseDate = nil;
```

Just tested this and it works like a champ.

**Edit3: full method as per comment thread**

```
- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender
{
    if(startsPressed < 1) {
        if(startPressed) return;
        startPressed = true;
        stopPressed =false;
        if(! _startDate)
        {
            self.startDate = [NSDate date];
        }
        else
        {
            if(_pauseDate)
            {
                NSTimeInterval startTime = _startDate.timeIntervalSince1970;
                NSTimeInterval pauseTime = _pauseDate.timeIntervalSince1970;
                NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = pauseTime - startTime;
                NSTimeInterval currentTime = [NSDate date].timeIntervalSince1970;
                NSTimeInterval newStartTime = currentTime - elapsedTime;
                _startDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:newStartTime];
                _pauseDate = nil;
            }
        }

        //create the stop watch timer that fires every 100ms
        self.stopWatchTimer =
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/100.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(updateTimer)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
    } else {

        startPressed = true;
        stopPressed = false;

    }
}
```

Comment: This would not factor out the "paused" time if Tom calculates his total time the same, as he's just calculating `current time - start time`.

Comment: @Stonz2 That's a good point, I will add consideration for that into my answer.

Comment: @Dima perhaps I am doing something wrong because when I click start nothing happens after applying this code.

Comment: @Dima I guess more so, where do you add this code mentioned above in my onStartPressed

Comment: @TomReinhart you put it in the first if statement, before you initialize the new timer. Let me know if that doesn't make sense and I will post the whole method, I was just trying to keep it simple.

Comment: @Dima yeah i'm sorry i'm a novice as you can tell. I tried inserting it like that and was getting my original error. Yeah i'd appreciate just this method. thanks dima

Comment: @TomReinhart I added it at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you reset `self.startDate` in the `onStartPressed` method. Do this only in `viewDidLoad:` and in `onResetPressed:`